# streamifier is not working, how to send buffer array to stream under this code?

Tags: node.js, express, stream, multer

I made some code to play video with buffer array, but when I submit the file, the browser just showed a empty video player like below.

[image]

here is my code

--view

```
block content
  h1= title
  p Welcome to #{title}

  form.upload(method='POST' enctype='multipart/form-data' action='')
    input#video(type='file' name='video')
    button#uploadButton(type='submit') Upload
```

--controller

```
exports.uploadVideo_post = function(req, res, next) {

  var fileName = req.file.buffer;

  console.log(req.headers);

  const size = req.file.size
  const range = req.headers.range;

  if (range) {
    let [start, end] = range.replace(/bytes=/, '').split('-');
    start = parseInt(start, 10);
    end = end ? parseInt(end, 10) : size - 1;
    res.writeHead(206, {
       'Content-Range': `bytes ${start}-${end}/${size}`,
       'Accept-Ranges': 'bytes',
       'Content-Length': (end-start) + 1,
       'Content-Type': 'video/mp4'
    })
    streamifier.createReadStream(fileName, { start, end }).pipe(res);
  } else {
    res.writeHead(200, {
      'Content-Length': size,
      'Content-Type': 'video/mp4'
    });
    (streamifier.createReadStream(fileName)).pipe(res);
  }

}
```

I used multer to get the uploaded file, and the 'fileName' is buffer array.
Can anybody help me to solve this problem?
In addition to that, it would be great if you can let me know how to re-design this player with the 'video' attribute on html.